# Why is it needed to instatiate PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean when having @EnableAsync configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, configuration

I have the following configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${my.value}"
    private String myValue;

    // The rest of the code
}
```

And it is working fine and `my.value` from properties is assigned to `myValue`.

But if I add `@EnableAsync` annotation to this class, it is not working.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${my.value}"
    private String myValue;

    // The rest of the code
}
```

This is the error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

It can be fixed by adding `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean in the class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${my.value}"
    private String myValue;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    // The rest of the code
}
```

Can someone explain me why is it needed to instantiate `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean when having `@EnableAsync` annotation?

Comment: "But if I add @EnableAsync annotation to this class, it is not working." what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: @Yuvaraj I added error

Comment: I checked with bare minimum spring boot project from spring initializer, it just works fine, irrespective of @EnableAsync the value prints, probably you are missing some details in the question(overriding any default configurations?!), which only you might know.

Comment: @Yuvaraj G thanks for checking!
I was thinking that it is generally known why this configuration can make trouble like this.